# Closures - Compilation vs Interpretation phase javascript

Tags: javascript, closures

// Code Starts

```
var a = 10;
function outer() {
    function inner() {
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
    };
    var b = 20;
    return inner;
}
var innerFn = outer();
innerFn();
```

// Code Ends

My Question is:

In Closures, the function remembers the scope information from the time the function object is created (In the above case, in the compilation phase) but at that time the assignments (for a and b) haven't really happened. So, how are the values for variables a and b retained.

Please correct me if something is wrong in the above statement.

Comment: a) a closure closes over a variable *scope*, not over values b) there is no "compilation phase"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said in your first sentence, the closure remembers the *scope information*. That includes the references to the variables, which already will have been declared (or are declared at the same time as the function). It does not matter what values these variables have - they are evaluated when the variables are actually used when the closure is called.

You will notice that when you overwrite `a` after having created the closure in the `outer()` call, it will give you the new value of `a` when calling `innerFn()`. Closures do *not* remember the *values* from the time of their creation.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a forum - it's a [Q&A site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :-P Welcome, btw.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the closure in this case is actually created when you return `inner`, not when you define the function `inner`.  Until you create a reference to a function, the closure mechanism would have no meaning.